# Obtaining FluentValidation max string length rules and their max values

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

We want to implement a character counter in our Javascript data entry form, so the user gets immediate keystroke feedback as to how many characters he has typed and how many he has left (something like "25/100", indicating current string length is 25 and 100 is the max allowed).

To do this, I would like to write a service that returns a list of dto property names and their max allowed lengths.

```
{Name='SmallComment', MaxLength=128}
{Name='BigComment', MaxLength=512}
```

The best way I can think of to do this would be to create an instance of the validator for that dto and iterate through it to pull out the .Length(min,max) rules.  I had other ideas as well, like storing the max lengths in an attribute, but this would require rewriting all the validators to set up the rules based on the attributes.

Whatever solution is best, the goal is to store the max length for each property in a single place, so that changing that length affects the validation rule and the service data passed down to the javascript client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain a single source of reference for both client/server I would take a metadata approach and provide a Service that returns the max lengths to the client for all types, something like:

```
public class ValidationMetadataServices : Service
{
    public object Any(GetFieldMaxLengths request)
    {
        return new GetFieldMaxLengthsResponse {
            Type1 = GetFieldMaxLengths<Type1>(),
            Type2 = GetFieldMaxLengths<Type2>(),
            Type3 = GetFieldMaxLengths<Type3>(),
        };        
    }

    static Dictionary<string,int> GetFieldMaxLengths<T>()
    {
        var to = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        typeof(T).GetPublicProperties()
          .Where(p => p.FirstAttribute<StringLengthAttribute>() != null)
          .Each(p => to[p.PropertyName] = 
              p.FirstAttribute<StringLengthAttribute>().MaximumLength);
        return to;
    }
}
```

But FluentValidation uses Static properties so that would require manually specifying a rule for each property that validates against the length from the property metadata attribute.